# Python: import a file from another directory

Tags: python, import, module

I am working in a set of directories with the following structure:

```
Master/
      Subfolder_1/file_1_1.py
                  file_1_2.txt
      Subfolder_2/file_2_1.py
```

I import file_1_1 in file_2_1 as follows:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../file_1_1')
```

file_1_1 is reading file_1_2.txt which is in the same directory. However, when I call the function that reads file_1_2.txt from file_2_1.py, it says no such file and directory and it gives me the path of file_1_2.txt as:

```
Master/Subfolder_2/file_1_2.txt
```

which is a wrong path. It seems like python in this case is using the working directory as a reference. How can I solve this error given that I don't want to include the absolute path for each file I read.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mess with `sys.path`, and don't think of imports as working against files and directories.  Ultimately everything has to live in a file somewhere, but the module hierarchy is a little more subtle than "replace dot with slash and stick a .py at the end".

You almost certainly want to be in `Master` and run `python -m Subfolder_1.file_1_1`.  You can use [pkg_resources](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html#basic-resource-access) to get the text file:

```
pkg_resources.resource_string('Subfolder_1', 'file_1_1.txt')
```

Comment: I actually run file_2_1 which uses file_1_1. So do you mean to run python -m Subfolder_2.file_2_1 ? If this is the case, I get this error: No module named Subfolder_2.

Comment: put an `__init__.py` in each "subfolder" so they both become packages.

Answer (score 0):

```
info=[]
with open(os.path.realpath('yourtextfile.txt','r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
       info.append(line)
```